# How to draw bitmap with rounded corners?

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-custom-view

I had the image that i get from url and put in the bitmap. Now I need to draw this bitmap with canvas and it required to be with rounded corners.

P.S

ImageView is not option here for me because there would be a lot of such images that should be drawn.

```
var url = "someurl"
var mediaMetadataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(url, HashMap<String, String>())
var frame:Bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(time)          // get image from url 
var rect = Rect(left, top, right, bottom)                               // coordinates for bitmap
canvas.drawBitmap(frame, null, rect, paint)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
public static float cornerRadius = 19.0f; 
public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path clipPath = new Path();
    RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

```
<CustomImageView
            android:id="@+id/selectIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```